# C言語 入力テキストを１行ずつスペースごとに抽出する方法

Tags: c

```
12 33 10 94 12 35 199
100 234 12 1 999 123 1 88 76 12
1 2 99 2
・・・・
```

のような入力テキストがあります。
１行にある数字の数は上記の例のように決まっていません。

これを１行ずつ単語ごとに読み取ろうとし、

```
char *tok;

while(fgets(readline,N,fp) !=NULL){
    //printf("%s",readline);
    tok = strtok(readline," ");
    while( tok != NULL ){
        printf( "%s¥n", tok );
        tok = strtok( NULL, " " );  /* 2回目以降 */
    }
}
```

というコードを書きました。
しかしコンパイル時に、

```
25:7: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
tok = strtok(readline," ");

28:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
tok = strtok( NULL, s2 );  /* 2回目以降 *
```

というエラーが出ました。

どうすれば
　・１行内の単語（数字）の数決まっていないテキストから
　・１行ずつ
　・１単語ごと
に分けて扱えるのでしょうか？
テキストでは数字はスペース区切りになっています。

Comment: この問題の解答に不可欠である、tok, s2の定義が不明です。

Comment: 定義を書きました。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: s2が" "に置き換えられた事で、コンパイルエラーが無くなり、プログラムが正常に動くようになったのではないですか？

Comment: `#include <string.h>`は書いてますか？

Comment: ありがとうございました。
#include <string.h>と#include <stdlib.h>を間違えていました。
#include <string.h>を書いたら動きました。

Comment: @I_Love_NLP さん。自己解決した場合は、自分で回答を書いて、解決に持っていくようにしてください。そうすることで、後から見た人の役に立つものになります。（丁寧に読み取りプログラム、エラーとヘッダ定義の関係を説明している資料になると思います。）

Comment: 解決したのであれば閉じて下さい。未解決の一覧に出てきてしまいます。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <string.h>
```

を追加したら動作しました。

ヘッダファイルを書き忘れないようにしましょう

Comment: おまけ：gccへのコンパイルオプションとして`-Wall`や`-W`を常につけた方がよいですね。今回の例であれば`warning: implicit declaration of function 'strtok'`のような警告メッセージを出してくれます。